# How rdmanifest are handled by ros_release?

Tags: ros, ros-release, rosdeb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
I am thinking of switching my 3rd party dependencies to rdmanifest.

The last thing that prevent me from doing so is that I am not too sure
whether ros_release will support this new architecture or not.

My question is simple: what will ros_release do about my 3rd party
dependencies expressed as rdmanifests?
I.e. will it correctly build them and transform them into binary debian
packages? Will it still be in /usr/local, is there anything particular
to take into account before trying to do so?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12191/how-rdmanifest-are-handled-by-ros_release?/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2011-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In it's current form the debian building pipeline cannot use anything but debian dependencies.  We are working toward upgrading our entire build system to be able to build non ros debians based on something similar to the rdmanifest, hopefully that will be out in Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-12-02**:
Sounds great! Could you let me know when there is an early version to test? I'd like to convert the octomap ROS wrapper package into a proper deb at some point (virtually no dependencies itself, though).